# How to show $\frac {\partial a^{T}X^{-1}b}{\partial X} = -\left( X^{-1}\right) ^{T}ab^{T}\left( X^{-1}\right) ^{T}$?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am struggling with this proof where $X$ is $m \times n$ matrix, $a$ is $m$ vector, $b$ is $n$ vector.

$$\frac {\partial a^{T}X^{-1}b}{\partial X} = -\left( X^{-1}\right) ^{T}ab^{T}\left( X^{-1}\right) ^{T}$$

I know $$\frac {\partial }{\partial X}f\left( X\right) ^{-1}=-f\left( X\right) ^{-1}\dfrac {\partial f\left( X\right) }{\partial x}f\left( X\right) ^{-1}$$

and am guessing to use this fact, I also know $\dfrac {\partial a^{T}Xb}{\partial X} = ab^{T}$.

When I use the chain rule I don't seem to get the form with the transposes.

I believe the result should be $\in \mathbb{R} ^{1\times \left( m\times n\right) }$

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the result is different, the result here is not $a^{T}b^{T}$ in the middle, as the function to be differentiated is not the same, and I am trying to understand how this works.

Comment: @JimSi The duplicate is more general, but your question is precisely the case where $A=a^T$ is a row matrix and $B=b$ is a column matrix. If you don't understand the duplicate you can ask a new question asking for clarification.

Comment: Agreed, I still don't know how the technique below exactly works. But yes you are of course right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we start deriving the gradient, some facts and notations for brevity:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  A : B C 
   &= BC : A \\
   &= A C^T   :  B  \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

Firstly, we obtain the differential for $X^{-1}$, which will be utilized for the gradient you are seeking: 
\begin{align}
d\left[X^{-1}X = I\right] &= dX^{-1} X + X^{-1}dX = 0 \\
&      \Leftrightarrow dX^{-1} = -X^{-1} dX X^{-1} \ .
\end{align}

Let $f := a^T X^{-1} b = a: X^{-1} b$.

Now, we can obtain the differential first, and then the gradient of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$.
\begin{align}
df  
&= a: dX^{-1} b \\
&= a: -X^{-1} dX X^{-1} b\\
&= -X^{-T} a b^T X^{-T}  : dX \\
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = -X^{-T} a b^T X^{-T}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, that taught me a lot. From $\langle A,B\rangle _{F}=\sum _{i,j}A_{ij}B_{ij}= tr\left( A^{T}B\right) = tr\left( AB^{T}\right) $ etc.

Comment: How common is this notation for the Frobenius inner product? It's certainly handy but I hadn't encountered it before.

Comment: I must admit that I don't know how common it is. But I know few people who use it (here in stack exchange for instance, e.g., greg, lynn, frank). Also, I have seen some lecture notes, e.g., http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/10-matrix.pdf (e.g., slide#17). Since it is a notation and turns out to be handy, then we should embrace it, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Hi @user550103, I'm having another look at this technique, as it appears really useful and I realise I don't understand. You have $f := a^T X^{-1} b = a: X^{-1} b = \langle a,X^{-1} b\rangle _{F}$

Comment: But then $df = \langle-X^{-T} a b^T X^{-T}, dX\rangle _{F}$, wouldn't that become $df = (-X^{-T} a b^T X^{-T})^{T}dX$

Comment: @JimSi $df = Tr(...)$