# Derivative of trace of a product containing an inverse matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

> What's the derivative of $$f(X)=\text{Tr}(YX^{-1})$$ with respect to $X$, where $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices of the same dimension?

My first attempt is to apply the chain rule as: Let $h(X)=X^{-1}$. So, $f(X)=\text{Tr}(Yh(X))$. Hence,

$$\frac{df(X)}{dX}=\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial h(X)}\cdot\frac{\partial h(X)}{\partial X}= Y \cdot - X^{-2}=-YX^{2}$$

I'm not sure of my answer.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3330818/550103

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use a Taylor expansion approach
$$
f(X + \varepsilon M) = tr( Y (X + \varepsilon M)^{-1})
= tr( Y X^{-1} (I + \varepsilon M X^{-1})^{-1})
$$
and
$$
(I + \varepsilon M X^{-1})^{-1} = I - \varepsilon M X^{-1} + O(\varepsilon^2)
$$
which yields
$$
f(X + \varepsilon M) = f(X) - \varepsilon tr( Y X^{-1} M X^{-1} ) + O(\varepsilon^2)
$$

Comment: To complete this answer, one may observe that $\Delta f = \text{tr}[(-X^{-1} Y X^{-1})\Delta X]$.

Comment: So the right answer is $-X^{-1}YX^{-1}$?

Comment: @Guess601: yes, the final answer is $-X^{-1} Y X^{-1}$

Comment: @user550103 You forgot to transpose.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for the feedback. I was too quick to write that (not my usual layout). But now I think the answer was in different layout. So, I think both transposed and non-transposed are equivalent but in the different layouts. Agreed?

Comment: It should be $$-X^{-T}Y^TX^{-T}$$