# Derivative with respect to the variance of Multivariate Gaussian

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normal-distribution, matrix-calculus

I am working on a multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and the variance-covariance $\Sigma \in S^{d\times d}$ where $S$ denotes the set of symmetric matrices.

When I am trying to maximize the log-likelihood of some observations (with respect to $\Sigma)$, I am basically trying to take the first-order conditions, and I need to derive the following:

$$\nabla_{\Sigma} \left( \mu^\top \Sigma^{-1}\mu \right)$$

This derivative is too complicated for me since $\Sigma$ is a matrix.

How can I solve these?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the distribution is multivariate -- I mean variance-covariance matrix

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3330806/339790

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo sorry for duplicate. Thank you!

Comment: No need to apologize. You're most welcome.